# Swift Apple Watch 2.0 verify didReceiveRemoteNotification received a notification

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Some time ago I wrote an app that works on my iPhone.  The app receives an order draft number via APN (Apple Push Notification) and uses web technologies to display the order details so it can be approved by the user.  On the iPhone everything works as expected.  The APN arrives, you select it, and can approve or reject the order referenced by the APN.  I have everything working on the watch except for the APN.  The APN arrives and the app starts, it shows an order for approval but it uses the hardcoded version, not the one that comes from the APN.

The APN takes the form of "New approval request for sales order draft XXX", where XXX is an integer.

I'm trying to use:

override func didReceiveRemoteNotification(remoteNotification: [NSObject : AnyObject], withCompletion completionHandler: ((WKUserNotificationInterfaceType) -> Void)) {
        // This method is called when a remote notification needs to be presented.
        // Implement it if you use a dynamic notification interface.
        // Populate your dynamic notification interface as quickly as possible.
        //
        // After populating your dynamic notification interface call the completion block.

```
    /*

    if let remoteaps:NSDictionary = remoteNotification["aps"] as? NSDictionary{
        if let remoteAlert:NSDictionary = remoteaps["alert"] as? NSDictionary{
            handleNotification( remoteAlert );
        }
    }

    let remoteaps:NSDictionary = (remoteNotification["aps"] as? NSDictionary)!
    handleNotification(remoteNotification )
    */

    let alert = remoteNotification["apps"]!["alert"]! as! NSDictionary

    var draftNum = alert ["body"] as! String
    draftNum = draftNum.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("New approval request for sales order draft", withString: "")
    MyDraft.draft = draftNum.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())


    completionHandler(.Custom)


}
```

myDraft.drafts is structure defined in InterfaceController.swift.  The code above is from NotificationController.swift.  I've spent a lot of time with Google but so far haven't found a method to proceed.  How do I confirm I was here?  Is there a better method to parse the APN?  How do I make print statements visible when I trigger the app via APN?  I've attached the debugger to the watch process but I've never seen anything in the Xcode output window.

Thank you,
Duncan

Comment: More research and I think the notification should be processed by override func handleActionWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification remoteNotification: [NSObject : AnyObject]) Still appears the function isn't called :(

Comment: If I use a simulated event the simulated watch app captures the event and extracts the order number. Exactly what I want it to do.  When I send an APN to the watch it calls the app but cannot pull the order number from the APN.  The simulated event and actual event are identical.  What am I missing?